# Partial Fraction with Arbitrary Numerator

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

So say I have a partial fraction with an arbitrary numerator as follows:

$$\frac{f(s)}{(s-s_1)\cdots(s-s_k)}$$ $$s_i\neq s_j, \forall i \neq j$$

With regards to decomposing it into the sum of fractions, can one always treat it as the following:

$$\frac{f(s)}{(s-s_1)\cdots(s-s_k)}=f(s)\frac{1}{(s-s_1)\cdots(s-s_k)} = f(s) \left( \frac{A_1}{(s-s_1)}+\cdots+\frac{A_k}{(s-s_k)} \right)$$

Or is there some special rule that can forbid this? (for example I know that if the top is a polynomial of degree less than the denominator you do not factor it out)

---

For anyone who is interested in more context, this question came to mind while working with Laplace transforms where I came across a similar example with $f(s)=e^{-s}$ where I know that it can be done but I do not have a solid enough understanding to know whether it can always be done or not

Comment: Did you think about the case where a root of f(s) is one of the s_i ? That is probably the only case where you run into an exception.

Comment: Be careful with denominator multiple roots.

Comment: @Cesareo Yes I should probably edit in a note about $s_i\neq s_j$ $\forall i\neq j$

Comment: @supreme_leader even if the function $f(s)$ is not a polynomial? Say $f(s)=\sinh(s)$ and there is some $s_i=0$. Thus both $f$ and the denominator have a root at 0

Comment: Let's take an even simpler case. If the numerator is s(s+1) and denominator is s(s-2), you can cancel out the s. But that assumes that s is not 0 or will define the Laplace transform differently at that root.